# Multiple VPNs active on iOS?

Tags: ios, vpn

Is it possible to have more than one VPN active at a time on iOS?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. What would you be tunneling to then?

Comment: one VPN might cover 192.168.0.0/16 and another might cover 10.0.0.0/8, for example.